# What do we need the "female-characters" tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

The review tool just prompted my to existence of the [female-characters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/female-characters) tag which currently has 8 questions. The [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1962/2565) that supposedly created the tag borders on recommendation or list-request, but is still on topic (and decently upvoted due to its age, I suspect it would have a decent chance of getting closed as not constructive if it had been asked today). The rest of the questions merely ask about characters who's gender happens to be female.

*All in all, do we really need this tag?*
If you suggest that we do, then please provide a set of guidelines (or at least a draft) on how to use the tag, and if there should also be a male counterpart tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So long as the norm for so much fiction are male characters and protagonists, yes, there'll be a need for a [female-characters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/female-characters).  This is simply because anything that isn't a male makes these works distinctive, and adds cultural baggage that isn't present with male-lead works.

Similarly, I'd expect a [female-authors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/female-authors) (or maybe 'creators' instead of 'authors').

There are a couple of examples of questions that make use of this quality of having female characters:

- [Was the nuanced treatment of Uhura a deliberate statement on civil rights and women's liberation?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/was-the-nuanced-treatment-of-uhura-a-deliberate-statement-on-civil-rights-and-wo)
- [Was there a common influence for the characters Leela on Futurama and Aeryn on Farscape](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3187/was-there-a-common-influence-for-the-characters-leela-on-futurama-and-aeryn-on-f)

And there's this one that comments on women in the US' Air Force:

- [How could Samantha Carter's words about the Gulf War be true?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-could-samantha-carter-s-words-about-the-gulf-war-be-true)

All of these are questions that arise from the previously-mentioned cultural baggage. And they point out some of the ways that female characters are a topic worthy of discussion specifically, which means they should have a tag.

Comment: Whole-heartedly agreed.

Comment: Should we then add a [tag:male-characters] tag or would that be unnecessary for the culture?